# Back up and restore Azure SQL Database schema

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

What are the best ways to Back up and restore Azure SQL Database schema in Azure cloud?

I have tried creating bacpac files, but problem with that is, it will be imported as a new database. I want to back up and restore specific schema only within the same database.

Another way i am looking at is creating a sql script file which contains data and schema using SSMS. But here size of the sql script is huge.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: What about using [bcp Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: Generate scripts in batches. First tables then views, functions, SPs etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. We can use [bcp Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) for exporting and importing the data in a fast way.

Comment: I have used in and out bcp commands for exporting and importing the data. created format files for each tables and referred that for the schema information. Able to generate scripts for all tables using another sql command. Found bcp tool very fast, could do 7 millions records (2.3 gb) from on premise data file to cloud azure sql in less than 8 minutes. Thank you

Comment: Got it. So we can use bcp  commands for exporting and importing the data in a fast way.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to back up and restore specific schema only within the same
> database.
> There is no native tool for Azure SQL Database that can do backup/restore of some certain schema.

The closest one to the requirements is a bacpac, however it can restore data into the empty or in a new database.

Therefore, a possible option is to move data out and then in using ETL tools like:

- SSIS
- ADF
- Databricks

Comment: Tried with bcp tool and worked perfectly. Thank you for your inputs we have tried ADF and Databricks as well but due to frequently changing schema in the source system, went ahead with  bcp